# i have to enable Lightning Design System and Account Teams through Apex Code

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, deployment, feature-activation

Currently Lightning Design System and Account Teams can be enabled by Manually But How to enable through apex code, this is our pre-deployment steps as per our requirement so can anyone Please help.

Comment: Remember that your app (is normally) not the only app in an org so changing settings that affect all apps isn't a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't enable Lightning through Apex alone. You need to go through the Lightning Set-up process which includes setting up MyDomain for your Developer Edition. I recommend you go to [Trailhead Enabling Lightning Experience Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lex_migration_introduction).